# Jenkins multibranch pipeline scan node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have configured multiple nodes in Jenkins and only one has an access to git server (firewall protection). I want to use specific node for Multibranch Pipeline scan, but I cannot find any option to do so. Is there possibility to define what machine should poll git repository?

Comment: have you tried adding labels to the pipeline and nodes?

Comment: You mean in Jenkinsfile? It won't work because polling is done before Jenkinsfile is interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

The branch scan happens on the Jenkins master, which obviously will need acess to the Git Service. However, the builds running on slaves will also need access to the Git service to clone the repo. Using labels that match the job to the slave node is the way to go.

Comment: So it looks that it is not possible to do it with specific node. Thank You for an information,

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately a bad design choice by Jenkins...